# Why can't I get the first element of a populated IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

```
    protected Server getServerByName(string name)
    {
        var servers = from qServer in db.Servers
                      where qServer.Name == name
                      select qServer;

        if (servers.Count() > 0)
        {
            return servers.First(); // The error occurs on this line
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This code has been working as expected up until now, however today it suddenly started giving this error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details.

I can't understand the error, even less than I can understand how this can happen. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: and what does *inner exception* say?

Comment: Oh dear. It highlights that my one of my column names didn't exist in the model (Presumably I forgot to migrate a chance). I've always selectively ignored the 'check inner exception' messages (Rather naively, it seems) thinking they were going to be compiled code stack traces or something equally cryptic. Sorry! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the InnerException, I found that I hadn't migrated the last model change to the database (EF CodeFirst). This exposed that I had added a column to the model without doing so to the database, and as a result it wouldn't obtain the object.

Fixed by migrating, although I'd like to thank martin_costello and Ehsan Sajjad for the FirstOrDefault tip, which makes my code look a lot nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this doesn't answer your question directly, your code is inefficient as you're performing two SQL queries.  You should use `FirstOrDefault()` instead, which will return `null` if there are no servers found.

```
protected Server getServerByName(string name)
{
    var servers = from qServer in db.Servers
                  where qServer.Name == name
                  select qServer;

    return servers.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Try this simplification and see if the original problem goes away.

Comment: Discovered problem in the comments of the OP, turns out to be a product of my forgetfulness (Forgetting to migrate a model change) and ignorance (Not checking the inner exception). Could I still accept this answer as it improves my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use **FirstOrDefault()** it will not throw exception if no record available.

```
return servers.FirstOrDefault();
```

It will simply return `null` if no item available.